# What characters have been killed on the show that haven't been killed on the books, and vice versa? (Show spoilers)

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In the recent Comic Con panel, Maisie Williams mentioned that there are some characters that have been killed in the show, that haven't been killed in the books, and vice versa.

What characters is she referring to? For example, in Season 4 Episode 10 (spoiler,)

> Jojen Reed dies. He hasn't died in the books yet.

Are there any other such characters?

Also, which characters have been killed in the books, that haven't been killed in the show? (Please don't mention it, if they are potentially killed in future of the show).

Comment: I haven't read the books, so I won't post it an answer, but I think Irri (one of the Dothraki maidens of the Khaleesi) lived longer in the books. She was killed in the second season when the dragons been taken. "It is known."

Comment: Grenn has not died in the books. I seem to recall there were more men in the Night's Watch who died in the show, but lived in the books. None of the riders Dany sent off in the desert were killed, they all came back alive. Drogo was challenged by one of the dothraki (Mago) and killed him, that did not happen in the books. Xaro is not killed in the books, but is alive and well. Those are a few I can think of off the top of my head.

Comment: Both of these comments are appropriate to post as answers.

Comment: I suspect there is a full list of differences somewhere on the internet. I feel if I posted this, it would be a rather incomplete list.

Comment: @dwjohnston: I haven't read the books, I'm acting on memory of reading something somewhere. I don't even remember where I'd read it. I don't find that to be a good motive for writing an answer. Someone else will surely come along soon and post it in an answer if it's true.

Comment: Not downvoting but answers to this question will always be incomplete as time & show progress until the end

Comment: "Jojen is one, he hasn't died in the books yet." Google 'Jojen Paste' for a rather disturbing theory.

Comment: @SystemDown, I had never heard of this - very disturbing!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In order of deaths, here are the people who have died on the show but are still alive in the books.

- Willas Wode (killed by hill tribes)
- Khal Mago (killed by Khal Drogo in a duel)
- Dany's bloodrider Rakharo (beheaded on the Red Waste)
- Qarth's Council of Thirteen (murdered by Pyat Pree and Xaro)
- Pyat Pree (killed by dragonfire)
- Xaro Xhoan Daxos (left to die in an impenetrable vault)
- Dany's handmaiden Irri (killed when Dany's dragons are stolen)
- Walder Frey's wife Joyeuse (killed by Catelyn)
- Grenn (killed fighting Mag the Mighty)
- Pyp (killed by Ygritte)
- Styr, Magnar of Thenn (killed by Jon)
- Jojen Reed (killed by spooooky skeletons)

The Game of Thrones wiki lists two offscreen deaths:

- The show writers have gone on record saying Old Nan died in between
  Season One and Season Two
- Ramsay Bolton killed all the Ironborn at Winterfell, meaning Dagmer Cleftjaw is most likely dead

A borderline case would be Robb Stark's wife, who is a totally different character in the books and show. In the book, she survives, while in the show she is killed at the Red Wedding.

As for those are still alive when they "should" be dead, its difficult to say with the way the the show plays fast and loose with the book timeline. But I can think of two characters who are dead by the end of the third book but are still alive on the show. I'd say there's a very good chance either could die on the show, so SPOILERS:

> Beric Dondarrion and Balon Greyjoy

Comment: I expect at least one (if not both) of these spoilers to happen in the fifth season. Hopefully at the beginning! Now that they are no longer bound by the books, I expect them to pick up the pace a bit faster.

Comment: @LordSnow No longer bound? Pick up the pace? They already skip so much good stuff, I'm not sure how much faster they could tear through the plot. And there are 2 books worth of story left, albeit the 2 books with the most filler material. It is not something to look forward to, when they run out of book material.

Comment: @LordSnow They are still bound by the book in many plotlines (though oddly, they've mostly run out of material for others, like Bran's).

Comment: @TLP: I believe I read, when this season ended, that they are going to develop story lines of their own. Based on the books for the most, I suppose, but not necessarily to follow it. The showrunners have stated several times that they expect a seven seasons run, eight at most. Even if they do go through these two books (simultaneously, since they can) for two seasons, and the new book is released during that time, and they adapt it to another season... do you expect Martin to finish the last book in that time?

Comment: @LordSnow They will have to do something to keep the show interesting. Both AFFC and ADWD had some serious issues in that regard. It is unlikely that GRRM will finish TWOW before season 6, much less the last book.

Comment: @TLP: Yes. That's my point. They are supposedly going to diverge from the books even more, even further. I mean, they already went into the Land of Always Winter (where else the White Walkers would live), why stop there? Maybe go to Ashai, or beyond the Sunset Sea! But in more seriousness, I do recall reading that they are going to go faster and diverge further from the books, probably with occasional shout outs to the story lines. I don't think it's necessarily a bad thing, though. Might be even a good thing.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield What are you saying? No UnCat?

Comment: Styr does die in the books; John sees him crushed under ice and wood when the stairs at Castle Black are set aflame and crumble.

Comment: Well she wouldn't be able to say she was coming back if she was. If she's not back by the third episode of season five I think it will be too late.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield That's quite the major rewrite. And quite the change of the Dondarrion/Arya storyline. They changed him from an honorable person who gives up his life to bring back Arya's mother, to someone who betrays Gendry and ends up on Arya's list. Major brainfarting going on in the HBO script writing team.

Comment: This answer needs to be updated now ;)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to those named in TenthJustice's excellent answer, there are also dozens of characters who have died in the books and have never appeared on-screen in the TV series. For example (book spoilers, of course):

> Pate, Donal Noye, Stafford Lannister, Maester Cressen, Vargo Hoat, Biter, Chiswyck, Arys Oakheart, and many many more.

There's also the odd character who has died in the TV series but never appeared in the books, e.g. Ros.

Comment: Wasn't that biter who bit the Hound on the neck, right before Arya stabbed Rorge?